# Linq cannot select Expression<Action>?

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to collect a bunch of function calls from an array, when I hit this issue:

`array.Select(x => () => Function(x))` will not work. No matter, how I play with it. The full working code of the application is simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //This won't work?
        //IEnumerable<Expression<Action>> expressions0 = values.Select(i => () => print(i));
        List<Expression<Action>> expressions1 = new List<Expression<Action>>();

        foreach (int i in values)
        {
            expressions1.Add(() => print(i));
        }
    }

    static int[] values = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

    static void print(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

I tried different things:

```
IEnumerable<Expression<Action>> expressions0 = values.Select(i => (() => print(i)));
IEnumerable<Expression<Action>> expressions0 = values.Select(i => {return () => print(i);});
```

Many others, but linq just doesn't want to let me get a collection of expressions.

Comment: It would help if you statet what error message you get

Comment: Given that you have a short, simple, effective, and correct solution, why are you not just using it?

Comment: @Servy It's not as effective as I wanted. Linq attracts me with the fact that instead of having actual variables that hold results, it holds an expression that spits out results when they are accessed. This builds a direct connection between the input and the output while keeping the data immutable.

Comment: Your data is neither large nor expensive to compute.  I find it unlikely you really need to defer creation of the values.  When doing so costs nothing, it's fine, but when it's causing you problems, and there's nothing to gain from it, just don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
IEnumerable<Expression<Action>> expressions0 
         = values.Select(i => (Expression<Action>) (() => print(i)));
```

(the compiler magic that will turn your lambdas into expression trees won't work there, so you need to be explicit on the casting).

Note however that you are using a closure there (`i`) and will probably fail if you attempt to invoke the compiled expression. The list of expressions would be there though (same as when you add them to the list on a `foreach` manually)

Not sure what you want to use this for

*Edit*: I just tested it, and it indeed fails to invoke because it fails to access `i` (https://dotnetfiddle.net/GMbswQ), however the actual insertion on the `IEnumerable<Expression<Action>>` works fine (i replaced `i` with a constant and voilá: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IlW3tW )

Comment: That worked out. I must be retarded to not have tried that. I have the arguments saved and restored as well, I just wanted to shrink code to minimal working sample. And this is absolutely the correct thing.